# NtDeviceIoControlFile - Getting size of buffer

Tags: c, winapi, tcp

I am calling `NtDeviceIoControlFile` with the `IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX` control code, but before performing the real call, I need to get the size of the output buffer so I can allocate an appropriate size for it.

Here is my code:

```
    TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX TcpRequestQuery;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK StatusBlock;
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(TDIENTITYID) * 4096;

    memset(&TcpRequestQuery, 0, sizeof(TcpRequestQuery));
    TcpRequestQuery.ID.toi_class = 0x100;
    TcpRequestQuery.ID.toi_type = 0x100;
    TcpRequestQuery.ID.toi_id = 0;
    TcpRequestQuery.ID.toi_entity.tei_entity = 0;
    TcpRequestQuery.ID.toi_entity.tei_instance = 0;

    *EntityList = (TDIENTITYID *) GlobalAlloc (GMEM_ZEROINIT, BufferSize);
    NTSTATUS Status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(
        TcpFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &IOBlock, IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX,
        &TcpQueryInfo, sizeof(TcpQueryInfo), *EntityList, BufferSize);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        return Status;

    BufferSize = StatusBlock.uInformation;
```

The problem is that the first call to `NtDeviceIoControlFile` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)`. The handle to the TCP device object is being opened with the `SYNCHRONIZE` flag set.

Question is why, and where?

Comment: *The handle to the TCP device object is being opened with the `SYNCHRONIZE` flag set* and so what ? `SYNCHRONIZE` this is not flag but desired access to device. may be you want use `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` option ? if you use it - All operations on the file are performed synchronously and you never got `STATUS_PENDING` and not need wait yourself. also if you want wait just after request - you need synchronous handle. asynchronous handle have sense only if you not wait after request, but handle it completion in callback. but `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because output buffer is 0.

Comment: example how use this ioctl is - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432313(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so you need allocate some output buffer and pass this buffer and size to `NtDeviceIoControlFile`. if buffer not big enough - you got `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` or `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` or `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` - in this case you need reallocate buffer. in some situation requested buffer size returned first bytes of your small buffer (only in case `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` and depend from concrete output structure). if buffer size not returned - you need somehow increment it yourself.

Comment: @RbMm I edited the question to the code like in example, but I cant even check for the buffer being too small because the output is still `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Comment: and why you use `0x100;` ? code is not readable with this. include *tdiinfo.h*  and use `INFO_CLASS_GENERIC`, `INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER` or what you want use ?

Comment: `INFO_CLASS_GENERIC` and `INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER` are both defined as `0x100`. I don't have TdiInfo.h so I am defining them directly - https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300-old/include/ddk/tdiinfo.h

Comment: @RbMm I even copied the exact code from the example you gave me on MSDN , and the return value in `GetLastError()` is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. So even the microsoft code documentation fails for me. What is going on? Would you mind giving me some sample code from your tests that works? Atleast for this call, and nothing more.

Comment: at first - nobody set last error in this case. you use ntapi - it return status to you. so which is status ?

Comment: @RbMm If you are asking about NTSTATUS return value, it is `-1073741811`.

Comment: @RbMm Okay I set `.Status = -1`, and `.Information = -1` AND after the call the `.Status` is still `-1`, but `.Information` is `4294967295`. What does this mean?

Comment: @RbMm So what can I do now? :( I'm really confused, I still didn't get it working!

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hello, yes I certainly can. I deleted the previous question due to negative comment, and side-chatter. Can you please give me your e-mail, and I will forward it your way. Thank-you!

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks, I will send you an e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <tdiinfo.h>
#include <tcpioctl.h>

NTSTATUS QueryTcp()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
#ifndef _WIN64

    struct TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW 
    {
        TDIObjectID     ID;                     // object ID to query.
        ULONG           pad;                    // ! for wow64 only - Context must be aligned on 8 byte in 64bit windows
        uchar           Context[CONTEXT_SIZE];  // multi-request context. Zeroed
    };

    PVOID Wow;
    status = NtQueryInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessWow64Information, &Wow, sizeof(Wow), 0);
    if (0 > status)
    {
        return status;
    }
#endif

    static const UNICODE_STRING ObjectName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\device\\tcp");
    static const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, const_cast<PUNICODE_STRING>(&ObjectName), OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, 
        const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa), &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PVOID InputBuffer;
        ULONG InputBufferLength;

#ifndef _WIN64
        if (Wow)
        {
            TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW req = {
                { { GENERIC_ENTITY }, INFO_CLASS_GENERIC, INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, ENTITY_LIST_ID }
            };

            InputBuffer = &req, InputBufferLength = sizeof(req);
        }
        else
#endif
        {
            TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX req = {
                { { GENERIC_ENTITY }, INFO_CLASS_GENERIC, INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, ENTITY_LIST_ID }
            };

            InputBuffer = &req, InputBufferLength = sizeof(req);
        }

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            TDIEntityID* pEntity;
        };

        volatile static UCHAR guz;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        ULONG cbAllocated = 0, cbNeed = 8 * sizeof(TDIEntityID);

        do 
        {
            if (cbAllocated < cbNeed)
            {
                cbAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(cbNeed - cbAllocated), stack);
            }

            if (0 <= (status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, buf, cbAllocated)))
            {
                if (ULONG n = (ULONG)iosb.Information / sizeof(TDIEntityID))
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        DbgPrint("{ %08x, %08x }\n", pEntity->tei_entity, pEntity->tei_instance);
                    } while (pEntity++, --n);
                }
            }

            cbNeed += 8 * sizeof(TDIEntityID);

        } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW || status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL);

        NtClose(hFile);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and output

```
{ 00000400, 00000000 }
{ 00000401, 00000000 }
{ 00000301, 00000000 }
{ 00000301, 00000001 }
{ 00000380, 00000000 }
{ 00000380, 00000001 }
{ 00000200, 00000015 }
{ 00000200, 00000014 }
{ 00000200, 00000013 }
{ 00000200, 00000012 }
{ 00000200, 00000011 }
{ 00000200, 00000010 }
{ 00000200, 0000000f }
{ 00000200, 0000000e }
{ 00000200, 0000000d }
```

then we can get concrete `TDIEntityID` from output array, copy it to `TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX` and make detail request on this entity, as described here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432313(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I appreciate your work, and everything, but even with your code - I am still getting `c000000d` in `status`. Its probably just a problem with my system then, I'm lost.

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - i dont think this. sure error in your code somewhere. and i doubt that you compile my code 1 to 1

Comment: I opened new project and put your code in there for test, and its returning `c000000d` man, there's no doubt, it just doesn't work. Honestly.

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - upload your test exe and paste link

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - this is because your exe not native - 32 bit failed on 64bit windows. if you build it as 64 bit code will be no error. for 32 bit need another structures use

Comment: Which structure do I need? My EXE should be able to run in Wow64 as 32-bit PE

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards need look, i not research this. may be this at all will be not worked from wow64 process. only from 64bit process on windows

Comment: If this is true, then how come `GetAdaptersAddresses` works in Wow64? Since it's internal uses this technique. I should mask `NtFsControlFile` in heavens gate (0x33 segment selector) technique to make it work, or how?

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - use another device and another ioctls. need look more for this ioctl in wow

Comment: You think its possible?

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - yes, worked. how i and guess - invalid input buffer size - must be 0x28 when in wow 0x24. now update code. 5 min

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you find this out if I can ask?

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - i update code - this new code work when compiled as 32 and as 64 bit code. and work as native and as wow64 process

Comment: This worked perfectly, as it appears - however my debugger is saying `Stack area around _alloca memory reserved by this function is corrupted`. What would be the reason for it? I've never used `alloca` before.

Comment: @itstartedwithkeyboards - this because you use run-time checks. off this. or use another memory allocation. my code is correct (cumulative allocation on stack) but this is incompatible with run-time checks

Comment: I don't understand this line: `PVOID stack = alloca(guz);` where `guz` is an uninitialized (and otherwise unused) variable.  Why not just `alloca(0)` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - `volatile static UCHAR guz;` this is static - so really 0. *Why not just alloca(0)* - because with optimization compiler simply drop this instruction (he have special knowledge for `alloca`) - as result wrong result and crash. but because i defined `guz` as `volatile` - never "optimization" here. so really `alloca(0)` is executed (for get stack pointer)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Personally I'd initialize `cbAllocated` to be equal to `cbNeeded` and then say `PVOID stack = alloca(cbAllocated);` but that's just a matter of personal style.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - no, this will be wrong with my code. `stack` - is marker, from which we calculate allocated size - `cbAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(buf , stack);`. it must be exactly `alloca(guz)` (in some case, when need constant size (*cb*) buffer after allocation, i use `stack=alloca(cb)`. the actual allocation is `buf = alloca(x)`

Comment: @HarryJohnston - may be this is very unusual style (cumulative allocation in stack) and it incompatible with run-time checks (need off it). but this is great work in user mode (in kernel we have too small stack).

Comment: I think I see - you're using `stack` to work out the total amount of space that has been allocated, which will typically be larger than the sum of the amounts requested, so as to not unnecessarily over-allocate.  Clever.  Perhaps *too* clever for my taste. :-)  I'm not sure whether this is all strictly legal from a language-lawyer perspective, but I can see why it works, and it is certainly efficient.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes. you correct understand my idea. and i remember that almost all say that use `union { X*p;Y*q};` also error by formal documentation. but i too good know that values of `p` and `q` in this case will be always the same. with any compiler and optimization. and only this i use in code. here not used memory aliasing, etc

Comment: @HarryJohnston - of course here is no great need use union, but some time, this construction let very serious simplify the code and make it more convenient - [example](https://pastebin.com/79FFmdLm) when i walk walk through variable size and types structures.