# NtDeviceIoControlFile (Query IP Address Entries) - STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST

Tags: c++, winapi, tcp

**TASK**

I am trying to enumerate the current ip interface entries using `NtDeviceIoControlFile` and `IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX` flag.

**CODE**

```
NTSTATUS GetIPAddresses(HANDLE TcpFile, TDIEntityID InterfaceID, IPAddrEntry* Entries, ULONG NumEntries) {
    TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW ReqWow64;

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IOBlock = {0, 0};
    NTSTATUS Status = -1;

    ReqWow64.ID.toi_class = 0x200;
    ReqWow64.ID.toi_type = 0x100;
    ReqWow64.ID.toi_id = 0x102;
    ReqWow64.ID.toi_entity = InterfaceID;

    return NtDeviceIoControlFile(
        TcpFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &IOBlock, IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX,
        &ReqWow64, sizeof(ReqWow64), Entries, NumEntries * sizeof(IPAddrEntry));
}
```

On [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432313(v=vs.85).aspx) page it says that I can

> 5. Obtain Address Information about a Particular IP Entity.
>
> If the ipsi_numaddr member of the IPSNMPInfo structure returned for a 
>   particular IP entity is nonzero, an array of IPAddrEntry structures can be retrieved by setting the ID.toi_entity member to identify the entity, the ID.toi_class to INFO_CLASS_PROTOCOL, the ID.toi_type to INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, and the ID.toi_id to IP_MIB_ADDRTABLE_ENTRY_ID. In this case, the output buffer should be allocated to hold an array of size
>
> sizeof(IPAddrEntry) * pIpSnmpInfoReturned->ipsi_numaddr

I have done this here:

```
IPAddrEntry *AddrEntries = Crt::Allocate<IPAddrEntry *>(SnmpInfo.ipsi_numaddr * sizeof(IPAddrEntry));
if (!AddrEntries)
    return STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
```

However, when I call the function:

```
NTSTATUS Status = GetIPAddresses(TcpFile, Interfaces[n], AddrEntries, SnmpInfo.ipsi_numaddr);
```

I get the following NTSTATUS `-1073741808` which in hex equals `0xC0000010` and this evaluates to [STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST](http://errco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_invalid_device_request/-1073741808/).

The declaration of the `TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW` structure

```
struct TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW  {
    TDIObjectID     ID;
    ULONG           pad;
    UCHAR           Context[16];
};
```

**QUESTION**

What is the reason for this error, and where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Could be caused by a bad declaration for the `TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW` structure, probably be a good idea to add that declaration to your question.  (I presume you've declared this yourself?  Google came up blank.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Updated with the structure definition.

Comment: There's a comment in `tdiinfo.h` that implies that `Context` might need to be zeroed before sending the request, have you tried that?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I've tried that, however it made no difference. Also, an aside (the e-mail I was supposed to send you last night, the issue was due to heap corruption, and It was solved, sorry for that).

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you got it sorted.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - this i define this struct. it need use only for wow64 processes. this because tcp driver assume 64bit structure layout only. this `pad` need for correct align `Context` on `ULONG_PTR` which is must be 8 byte in 64 bit windows. here all ok. but `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` usual returned when request sent to wrong device or wrong ioctl. otherwice will be another error - invalid parameter, buffer small, not supported..

Comment: @RbMm From where you get all this information, is there a documentation you are referencing (Please share)? You know so much!

Comment: `TDIObjectID` is 5 `DWORD` - so always 20 bytes. next member `Context` is defined as `ULONG_PTR` . so for 32 bit it will be at 20 offset. but on 64bit - it must be 8 byte align - so at 24 offset. for 32 bit process and need this 4 byte pad before `Context`, for force it be at 24 byte offset. driver is 64 bit and wait 64 bit layout structure here.

Comment: but you sure that you use correct device handle and ioctl here ? error say about this.

Comment: Yes, I opened device handle like you said in your previous answer (with `SYNCHRONIZE` flag and name `\device\tcp`) and IOCTL is `IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX`.

Comment: in this case you use incorrect `InterfaceID` what is `tei_entity` here ?

Comment: It's a filled structure as `InterfaceID {tei_entity=1343226219 tei_instance=2005023955 }`

Comment: of course this incorrect. you must copy it from returned `ENTITY_LIST_ID` list request. will be next [values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432492(v=vs.85).aspx) - 300,301,380,400,401. and please - use **hex** form always. and not say `0x102;` but `IP_MIB_ADDRTABLE_ENTRY_ID` - your code not redable with this numeric constants

Comment: @RbMm What do you mean I must copy it from `ENITITY_LIST_ID` ? From where exactly?

Comment: of course you need copy it. from first request - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46544861/6401656 - view output - { 00000400, 00000000 }.. - from here

Comment: ok, this code implement all 6 points from [IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX control code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432313(v=vs.85).aspx) - and all worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iptypes.h>
#include <tdiinfo.h>
#include <tcpioctl.h>

NTSTATUS QueryTcp()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
#ifndef _WIN64

    struct TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW 
    {
        TDIObjectID     ID;                     // object ID to query.
        ULONG           pad;                    // ! for wow64 only - Context must be aligned on 8 byte in 64bit windows
        uchar           Context[CONTEXT_SIZE];  // multi-request context. Zeroed
    };

    PVOID Wow;
    status = NtQueryInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessWow64Information, &Wow, sizeof(Wow), 0);
    if (0 > status)
    {
        return status;
    }
#endif

    static const UNICODE_STRING ObjectName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\device\\tcp");
    static const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, const_cast<PUNICODE_STRING>(&ObjectName), OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, 
        const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa), &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PVOID InputBuffer;
        ULONG InputBufferLength;
        TDIObjectID* pID;
        PVOID Context;

#ifndef _WIN64
        if (Wow)
        {
            TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX_WOW req = {
                { { GENERIC_ENTITY }, INFO_CLASS_GENERIC, INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, ENTITY_LIST_ID }
            };

            InputBuffer = &req, InputBufferLength = sizeof(req), pID = &req.ID, Context = req.Context;
        }
        else
#endif
        {
            TCP_REQUEST_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX req = {
                { { GENERIC_ENTITY }, INFO_CLASS_GENERIC, INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, ENTITY_LIST_ID }
            };

            InputBuffer = &req, InputBufferLength = sizeof(req), pID = &req.ID, Context = req.Context;
        }

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            TDIEntityID* pEntity;
        };

        volatile static UCHAR guz;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        ULONG cbAllocated = 0, cbNeed = 8 * sizeof(TDIEntityID);

        do 
        {
            if (cbAllocated < cbNeed)
            {
                cbAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(cbNeed - cbAllocated), stack);
            }

            // 1. Enumerate TDI Entities (INFO_CLASS_GENERIC, INFO_TYPE_PROVIDER, ENTITY_LIST_ID)

            if (0 <= (status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, buf, cbAllocated)))
            {
                if (ULONG n = (ULONG)iosb.Information / sizeof(TDIEntityID))
                {
                    NTSTATUS s;

                    union {
                        ULONG type;
                        IPSNMPInfo snmp;
                        IFEntry ife;
                        IPInterfaceInfo ii;
                        BYTE iii_addr[sizeof(IPInterfaceInfo) + MAX_PHYSADDR_SIZE];
                        BYTE if_descr[sizeof(IFEntry) + MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH];
                    };

                    cbAllocated = 0;
                    stack = buf;
                    PVOID pv = 0;

                    do 
                    {
                        DbgPrint("***{ %08x, %08x }\n", pEntity->tei_entity, pEntity->tei_instance);

                        // set Specific Entity.
                        pID->toi_entity = *pEntity;

                        switch (pEntity->tei_entity)
                        {
                        case IF_ENTITY:
                            //3. Obtain MIB-II Information about an Interface Entity.
                            pID->toi_id = IF_MIB_STATS_ID;
                            pID->toi_class = INFO_CLASS_PROTOCOL;

                            s = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, 
                                InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, if_descr, sizeof(if_descr));

                            DbgPrint("#%u type=%u mtu=%u %.*S\n", ife.if_index, ife.if_type, ife.if_mtu,
                                ife.if_descrlen / sizeof(WCHAR), ife.if_descr);
                            break;

                        case CO_NL_ENTITY:
                        case CL_NL_ENTITY:
                            //4. Obtain MIB-II Information about a Particular IP Entity. 
                            pID->toi_id = IP_MIB_STATS_ID;
                            pID->toi_class = INFO_CLASS_PROTOCOL;

                            s = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, 
                                InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, &snmp, sizeof(snmp));

                            if (0 <= s)
                            {
                                if (snmp.ipsi_numaddr)
                                {
                                    cbNeed = snmp.ipsi_numaddr * sizeof(IPAddrEntry);

                                    if (cbAllocated < cbNeed)
                                    {
                                        cbAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(cbNeed - cbAllocated), stack);
                                    }

                                    // 5. Obtain Address Information about a Particular IP Entity
                                    pID->toi_id = IP_MIB_ADDRTABLE_ENTRY_ID;

                                    s = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                                        IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, 
                                        InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, pv, cbAllocated);

                                    if (0 <= s)
                                    {
                                        IPAddrEntry* pAddr = (IPAddrEntry*)pv;

                                        // 6. Obtain Interface Information about a Particular IP Address.
                                        pID->toi_id = IP_INTFC_INFO_ID;

                                        do 
                                        {
                                            char sz[16], mask[16];
                                            RtlIpv4AddressToStringA(&pAddr->iae_addr, sz);
                                            RtlIpv4AddressToStringA(&pAddr->iae_mask, mask);
                                            DbgPrint("[%s/%s]\n", sz, mask);

                                            // 6. Obtain Interface Information about a Particular IP Address.
                                            memcpy(Context, &pAddr->iae_addr, sizeof(pAddr->iae_addr));

                                            s = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                                                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, 
                                                InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, &ii, sizeof(iii_addr));

                                            if (0 <= s)
                                            {
                                                if (ii.iii_addrlength)
                                                {
                                                    DbgPrint("addr=");
                                                    PBYTE pb = ii.iii_addr;
                                                    do 
                                                    {
                                                        DbgPrint("%02x", *pb++);
                                                    } while (--ii.iii_addrlength);
                                                    DbgPrint("\n");
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } while (pAddr++, --snmp.ipsi_numaddr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case CO_TL_ENTITY:
                        case CL_TL_ENTITY:

                            //2. Obtain Type Information about a Specific TL Entity.
                            pID->toi_id = ENTITY_TYPE_ID;
                            pID->toi_class = INFO_CLASS_GENERIC;

                            s = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                                IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX, 
                                InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, &type, sizeof(type));

                            if (0 <= s)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("type=%x\n", type);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:continue;
                        }

                        if (0 > s)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("error=%x { %08x, %08x }\n", s, pEntity->tei_entity, pEntity->tei_instance);
                        }

                    } while (pEntity++, --n);
                }
            }

            cbNeed += 8 * sizeof(TDIEntityID);

        } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW || status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL);

        NtClose(hFile);
    }

    return status;
}
```